# Passing PHP variable to remote bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell, get, ssh2-exec

Is there a method similar to PHP's GET for bash scripts?

This is what I'm trying to do...

PHP file sets a variable and executes a remote bash script, the variable gets passed and is used in the bash script.

So this is my PHP script...

```
 <?php
 $myvar = 'hello world';

 $connection = ssh2_connect('example.com', 22);
 ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

 $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/incoming/myscript.sh');
 ?>
```

And this is myscript.sh on the remote machine...

```
 #!/bin/bash          
 echo $myvar
```

Of course this isn't working because I'm not sure how to pass $myvar from the PHP file to myscript.sh

I know with PHP this is done using GET but how do I do this in this situation?

Comment: Parameters in shell scripts are referenced as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`... Just add them to your exec call: `ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/incoming/myscript.sh param1 param2');`.

Comment: Your shell script **cannot** see php variables. If you set the variable in the php processes environment then it should be available in the shell script's environment (and the environment of every other process your php script spawns) and then your shell script should just work. You can also pass the variable to the script as an argument on its command line.

Comment: Yes but how do I get them there from the PHP script?

Comment: @EtanReisner could you give me an example of how to set the correct variable please?

Comment: @Grant See the edit to my comment.

Comment: @Phylogenesis thanks man just saw that. Still a little confused though. So in PHP I set $1 = 'hello world'; then in the exec command I use ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/incoming/myscript.sh param1'); ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Phylogenesis commented, you want to simply put the variables after the script call, then call in the bash script use `$1` to read the var:

https://eval.in/439053

```
$stream = "/usr/incoming/myscript.sh " . escapeshellarg($myvar);
```

Your bash script would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash          
 echo "$1"
```

Comment: This will break (and break badly) if the value of `$myvar` in php can contain single quotes. Variables that need to be expanded on the command line **need** to be properly escaped to be safe.

Comment: Ahh ok now it makes sense, so I pass it like you mentioned above and then call it in the script with $1 right?

Comment: lol beat me to it.. perfect, thanks for explaining that Chris ;)

Comment: More likely something like escapeshellarg()

Comment: I'm actually not sending anything funky in the variable, no spaces or strange characters so it's not an issue in my case but very handy to know.

Comment: Yeah, `addslashes` is **not** shell safe escaping at all.

Comment: And no, you don't do that *only* if it might contain something. You **always** do it **because** it might contain something. Anything else is a security issue waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks @JonStirling, updated the answer using `escapeshellarg()`.

Comment: The bash script should quote `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell, even through SSH. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getRemoteHost('example.com')->getShellBySsh('username', 'secretPassword');

//instead of triggering a script, just trigger the individual commands i.e.:
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd("echo \$myvar");
```

Answer (score -1):

script.php

```
 <?php
 $myvar = 'hello world';
 $myvar = escapeshellarg($myvar);
 $connection = ssh2_connect('example.com', 22);
 ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
 $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/incoming/myscript.sh '.$myvar);
```

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash          
echo $1
```

Comment: This will print `hello` from the shell script as `$myvar` will be word-split by the shell. Variables that need to be expanded on the command line **need** to be properly escaped to be safe.

Comment: i believe escapeshellarg will do